# Unable to redirect after user_save

Tags: users

I am unable to redirect back to the page after executing the `user_save`. Following is my code snippet:

```
//if the response code is failed rollback the user changes and redirect
if ($results['code']!=200) {
  user_save(NULL,$account);
  drupal_goto("/admin/people");
}
```

Comment: what does user_save() return? can you try to put an echo statement after user_save()?

Comment: Are you working on your custom module for the same?

Comment: Thanks develkar. It was my mistake I modified the code user_save(NULL,$edit);

Comment: @JayeshJose I was about the comment the same thing, but somehow missed it. The second argument to `user_save` should be an array and not the object. Anyways it is good that you figured it out yourself. Please answer your own question, and accept it after a day so that the question gets out of the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below format:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'form_id_goes_here') {
    // Code here
    $form['#submit'][] = '_mymodule_test_registration_submit';
  }
}

function _mymodule_test_registration_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Code here
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'path1/path2/mypage';
}
```